# Print only words that are in File A not in B

Tags: shell, unix

I have two files and I need to print the words only (not complete lines) that are in the first file not in the second file. I have tried `wdiff` but it prints complete lines and is not useful.

Sample of file:

```
وكان مكنيل وقتها رئيس رابطة مؤرخي أمريكا ـ 
كما فهمت - من شاهد الحادثة. ثم يصف كيف قدم 
مكنيل الرجلين الخصمين, فكانت له صرامته, إذ 
حدد عشرين دقيقة فقط لكل منهما أن يقدم رأيه 
وحجته, ثم وقت للرد, ثم يجيبان عن أسئلة قليلة 
من القاعة, والمناقشة في وقت محدد.
```

Comment: Provide some sample data from both files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make two files that contain each word on its own line, and sort them. Then use `comm`:

```
$ cat fileA

ﻮﻛﺎﻧ ﻢﻜﻨﻴﻟ ﻮﻘﺘﻫﺍ ﺮﺌﻴﺳ ﺭﺎﺒﻃﺓ ﻡﺅﺮﺨﻳ ﺄﻣﺮﻴﻛﺍ ـ
ﻚﻣﺍ ﻒﻬﻤﺗ - ﻢﻧ ﺵﺎﻫﺩ ﺎﻠﺣﺍﺪﺛﺓ. ﺚﻣ ﻲﺼﻓ ﻚﻴﻓ ﻕﺪﻣ

$ cat fileB

ﻮﻘﺘﻫﺍ ﺮﺌﻴﺳ ﺭﺎﺒﻃﺓ ﺄﻣﺮﻴﻛﺍ ـ
ﻚﻣﺍ ﻒﻬﻤﺗ - ﻢﻧ ﺵﺎﻫﺩ ﻲﺼﻓ ﻚﻴﻓ ﻕﺪﻣ

$ tr ' ' '\n' < fileA | sort > fileA-sorted
$ tr ' ' '\n' < fileB | sort > fileB-sorted
$ comm -23 fileA-sorted fileB-sorted

ﺎﻠﺣﺍﺪﺛﺓ.
ﺚﻣ
ﻢﻜﻨﻴﻟ
ﻡﺅﺮﺨﻳ
ﻮﻛﺎﻧ

$
```

This can also be written on a single line in bash:

```
comm -23 <(tr ' ' '\n' < fileA | sort) <(tr ' ' '\n' < fileB | sort)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but a comment too long to be a comment. I'm sorry - I don't yet know the etiquette in this case, so please let me know if there's a better way to do this.

I thought both the approaches given in other answers were interesting, but was concerned that the `grep` version would require `m * n` comparisons, where `m` and `n` are the numbers of words in each file respectively.

I'm running `bash` on OSX and ran the following smoke test to compare:

Grab two random selections of 10K words from my dictionary:

```
gsort -R /usr/share/dict/words | head -n 10000 > words1
gsort -R /usr/share/dict/words | head -n 10000 > words2
```

Compare the running time for each solution:

Using `comm`:

```
time comm -23 <(tr ' ' '\n' < words1 | sort) <(tr ' ' '\n' < words2 | sort)
```

Result:

```
real    0m0.143s
user    0m0.225s
sys     0m0.018s
```

Using `grep`:

```
time grep -wf <(tr ' ' '\n' < words1) <(tr ' ' '\n' < words2)
```

Result:

```
real    1m25.988s
user    1m25.925s
sys     0m0.063s
```

I'm not sure about memory complexity. I'd be interested in any criticism of this analysis, or commentary on how to evaluate which solution is better?

Comment: Nice analysis. Where does `gsort` come from? It's not standard on OSX.

Comment: I got it by doing `brew install coreutils`. `-R` is an option available in the gnu implementation of `sort`, but not on mac. I originally found this information on SO, but can't find the link anymore I'm afraid.

Comment: Ah: it just came back to me. See the accepted answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/334450/equivalent-of-gnu-sort-r-on-osx

Comment: Comm+Sort uses constant ram and linear disk space, at least in the GNU versions. I imagine grep uses linear ram.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid sorting (specially if input files are pretty huge) using `grep`:

```
grep -wf <(tr ' ' '\n' < file1) <(tr ' ' '\n' < file2)
```